# Converting SIP to TDM?

Tags: telephony, voice

We're looking to implement DID calling. Our local provider has indicated they can provide this via a SIP trunk, but cannot provide an E1. We also don't think they can provide an E1-over-SIP (where they convert a TDM signal to SIP on their end).

For various unrelated (non-technical) reasons, we cannot connect a SIP trunk to our PBX, only an E1/T1.

Question: Do solutions exist that would allow us to convert a straight SIP trunk to a TDM E1 for connection to our PBX? What are some examples?

The PBX is a Meridian Option 11C, if that matters.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, this is certainly possible.  You can install a E1/PRI VWIC in a Cisco router and the Cisco router can act as a gateway between TDM and SIP.  There are of course solutions by other vendors.  This is a fairly broad subject, so you will need to read up on it, but it is defiantly possible.